# Update rule for multivariate linear regression with vector outputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

In multivariate linear regression the weight (**w**) update rule is

```
w[i] += learning_rate * sum([x[j][i] * (y[j] - h(x[j])) for j in range(len(x))])
```

Where **x** is the datamatrix (the vector of feature-vectors), **y** the vector of real numbered outputs and

```
def h(x):
    return sum([w[i]*x[i] for i in range(len(weights))])
```

What would be the equivalent weight update rule if **y** was a vector of real numbered vector outputs?